# Can't get users list of "Like"

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-fql

Although I wrote FQL searching from the person who pushed the "Like" button, it does not work normally.
ex) SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id='10150931418786729' AND object_type='link'

Once, according to the question by other persons, he answered it was the privacy problem. However, a result is empty even if it focuses on me.
ex) SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() and object_type='link'

It seems that a result can be got if object_type is not specified(That is, "Like" to albums).
ex) SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id='10150931418786729'
(*http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10150629589136729.412063.20531316728)

Does a FQL query have a problem? Or does Facebook API have?

Append: This query is also failed...
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id IN (SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = "http://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/1204/18/news107.html") AND object_type="link"

Answer (score 1):

like is a restricted keyword.

wrap it in ` ` to use it:

Eg:

```
SELECT * FROM `like` ...
```

Comment: Like is not restricted keyword, because that is not SQL and is FQL. Rather, an syntax error occurs.